# Getting crash while take up singed apk with proguard enabled in my cases

Tags: android, proguard, android-livedata

I am using live data observing concept -- When hide this line and take up build it was working fine . if i enable the below code getting

```
  viewModel.loadValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<String?> {
        toSelectPlaceSearchValue(it.toString())
    })
```

getting the below error

```
  at .fragment.a(SourceFile:32)
    at g.j.a.c.j.i.j.a(SourceFile:7)
    at g.j.a.c.h.i.e.onTransact(SourceFile:3)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:504)
    at dx.aZ(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210915051@21.09.15 (040408-0):2)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bj.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210915051@21.09.15 (040408-0):1) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1065)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

My Proguard file txt

-keep class androidx.lifecycle.* { *; }

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to add these two lines in your proguard rules, it will definitely work.

```
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel 
  {
    <init>();
  }
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel 
  {
    <init>(android.app.Application);
  }
```

checkout the [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/lifecycle/viewmodel/proguard-rules.pro) for the reference.

Comment: open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {
       /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
this is import -- Class getting error at com.fragment.a(SourceFile:32)  -- Import class 
 at g.j.a.c.j.i.j.a(SourceFile:7)  at g.j.a.c.h.i.e.onTransact(SourceFile:3)
getting force closed

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
`-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }`

Comment: Tried but im getting the error in Open class Event import ..
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

var hasBeenHandled = false
    private set // Allow external read but not write

/**
 * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
 */
fun getContentIfNotHandledOrReturnNull(): T? {
    return if (hasBeenHandled) {
        null
    } else {
        hasBeenHandled = true
        content
    }
}